# Tensorflow data readers: readning the same files repeatedly until training ends

Tags: tensorflow

I've created a model in tensorflow using [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/) tutorial, on an example data set I've created. The model feeds the data in the input files until they end and then stops.

This is how I read the files:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=record_bytes)
result.key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
```

This is the session.run call:

```
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
                hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=max_steps)],  
                ) as mon_sess:

    while not mon_sess.should_stop():
        mon_sess.run(train_op)
```

The inner loop stops when the files end.

**I want the model to continue until `max_steps` is reached, repeatedly reading the same files as necessary.**

I know this can be done manually, by passing the data to the session in a `feed_dict`, but I'm hoping there's an easier way that allows me to still use the built-in file readers.

Comment: Does the `num_epochs` argument to the `string_input_producer` work for you? [limit_epochs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/input_pipeline#limit_epochs) might also be useful.